# Python, pandas How to split a string by finding a specific word rather then "," or "_" and etc

Tags: python, pandas, split, pandasql

I'm having hard time trying to extract an id number from a string.

I could get it using index but it would fail for the other rows of the data-frame.

How do I extract `campaignid=351154190`, in a such way that would work for all rows.

only pattern is the word `campaignid`, need extract and store in new column in the data-frame. Performance is not crucial in this task.

## Original string

```py
https:_utm_source=googlebrand&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=brand&utm_campaignid=3
51154190&keyword=aihdisadjiajdutm_matchtype=e&device=m&utm_network=g&utm_adposit
ion=1t1&geo=9027258&gclid=CjwKCsadjjsaopdl[psdklksfdosjfidj9FOk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD
_BwE&affiliate_id=asdaskdosjadiasjdisaj-asdhasuigdyusagdyusagyk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE&utm_content=search&utm_contentid=1251489456158180&placement&extension
```

## Spliting the string

`x= cw.captureurl.str.split('&').str[:-1]`

## printing one row

`print(x[25])`

```py
['https:_utm_source=googlebrand', 'utm_medium=ppc', 'utm_campaign=brand', 
'utm_campaignid=35119190', 'keyword=co',
 'utm_matchtype=e', 'device=m', 'utm_network=g', 'utm_adposition=1t1',
 'geo=9027258', 'gclid=CjwKCAjwnMTqBRAzEiwAEF3ndo3-
CNOsp1VT5OIxm0BuUcSWQEwtJSR5KLiJzrvjjc9FOk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE',
 'affiliate_id=CjwKCAjwnMTqBRAzEiwAEF3ndo3-
CNOsp1VT5OIxm0BuUcSWQEwtJSR5KLiJzrvjjc9FOk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE', 
'utm_content=search', 'utm_contentid=1211732930', 'placement']
```

It would be great if I could use something that would search for the word "campaignid" (what is my target)

Then store it in another column of the some data-frame.

I tried doing a split after split, it didn't work
I tried using for loop with if statement, didn't work also.

Comment: `s.str.extract('(campaignid=\d+)')`?

Comment: Thank you Quang, it works almost perfect, only issue is it returning the output 

"campaignid=35119190" rather then just number "35119190"

Comment: change it to `s.str.extract('campaignid=(\d+)')`.

Comment: Perfect!! thank you very much Quang Hoang!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```
campaign_id = cw['captureurl'].str.extract('campaignid=(\\d+)')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you Code Different, it works almost perfect, only issue is it returning the output "campaignid=35119190" rather then just number "35119190"

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `urllib`. In particular, the `parse_qs` function will get a dictionary of string arguments. https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Using your example URL we get:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

test = 'https:_utm_source=googlebrand&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=brand&utm_campaignid=351154190&keyword=aihdisadjiajdutm_matchtype=e&device=m&utm_network=g&utm_adposition=1t1&geo=9027258&gclid=CjwKCsadjjsaopdl[psdklksfdosjfidj9FOk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE&affiliate_id=asdaskdosjadiasjdisaj-asdhasuigdyusagdyusagyk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE&utm_content=search&utm_contentid=1251489456158180&placement&extension'

print(parse_qs(test))
```

```
{'https:_utm_source': ['googlebrand'],
 'utm_medium': ['ppc'],
 'utm_campaign': ['brand'],
 'utm_campaignid': ['351154190'],
 'keyword': ['aihdisadjiajdutm_matchtype=e'],
 'device': ['m'],
 'utm_network': ['g'],
 'utm_adposition': ['1t1'],
 'geo': ['9027258'],
 'gclid': ['CjwKCsadjjsaopdl[psdklksfdosjfidj9FOk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE'],
 'affiliate_id': ['asdaskdosjadiasjdisaj-asdhasuigdyusagdyusagyk033DKW1xoCXlwQAvD_BwE'],
 'utm_content': ['search'],
 'utm_contentid': ['1251489456158180']}
```

To get the campaignids for the entire dataframe, we can use a `.apply` to get this done:

```
# After parsing each url's arguments, we extract the first campaignid from the dictionary's list.
df['utm_campaignid'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: parse_qs(x)['utm_campaignid'][0])
df.head()
```

```
    url utm_campaignid
0   https:_utm_source=googlebrand&utm_medium=ppc&u...   351154190
```